# PowerBI generate table from another table

Tags: powerbi, dax

Good morning,

I have the following table with RAW data:

```
USER   |   YEAR   |   I1   |   G1   |   I2   |   G2   |   I3   |   G3
A      |   2021   |   1    |   3    |   4    |   2    |   5    |   1
B      |   2021   |   3    |   2    |   1    |   2    |   4    |   1
```

And I need to create from this table another table, generating 3 new lines per Table A line.

```
USER   |   YEAR   |   #   |   I   |    G
A      |   2021   |   1   |   1   |    3
A      |   2021   |   2   |   4   |    2
A      |   2021   |   3   |   5   |    1
B      |   2021   |   1   |   3   |    2
B      |   2021   |   2   |   1   |    2
B      |   2021   |   3   |   4   |    1
```

I cannot find how to do it in PowerBI. I worked with other languages in which I would face this by extracting 3 times the information from the first table (in the first extraction I would select the I1 and G1, in the second one the I2 and G2 and in the third one the I3 and G3) and I would append it. However, I am not able to find in google how to do this with DAX.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you so much,

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are asking how to do this with DAX simply because this is the only way you've heard. In Power BI, you should do such transformation [using M](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/), i.e. in [Power Query Editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-quickstart-using-power-bi).

The format of the data is not optimal, so you will need to transform it a bit more. So open Power Query Editor by clicking on `Transform data` button in the ribbon, and then make a copy of your table by right-clicking it in the list and select `Duplicate`. Delete `I1`, `I2` and `I3` columns from one of the tables, and delete `G1`, `G2` and `G3` columns from the other. In each of the tables, select all three `Ix`/`Gx` columns and click `Transform` -> `Unpivot Columns`. After this step, the tables should looks like this:

[image]

Rename `Values` columns to `I` and `G`, and in each of the tables split the `Attribute` column by right clicking the column title and selecting `Split column` -> `By number of characters...` like this:

[image]

Rename the column with the numeric value (`Attribute.2`) to `#` in both tables and remove the other one (`Attribute.1`). After this stage, you should have two tables with the first 3 columns the same, and `I` and `G` columns containing the numeric values:

[image]

Now you must merge these two tables together, by clicking  the drop down of `Home` -> `Merge Queries` and selecting `Merge Queries as New`, then select your two tables and select `USER`, `YEAR` and `#` columns as keys in both lists:

[image]

Expand the table by clicking the button in the columns title:

[image]

And leave only the other value, so at the end (after renaming the columns) you will get the desired result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I will work on this. Is the M quicker than DAX?

Comment: I was trying to calculate a measure in that table in DAX resulting on something like: USER|I|G   -   A|10|6   -   B|8|5. But I cannot come up with the DAX statement. I used to do this with SUMMARIZE ON USER SUBTOTAL I G, but I am getting confused with DAX.

Comment: It is not that M is faster or slower than DAX. They are just different things. Power Query/M in general is the place where you load and transform your data. DAX is more the place where you implement the logic of the report.